# Перемешать все буквы в строке во всех возможных вариацих

Tags: python, алгоритм, функции, случайные-числа

Пользователь вводит строку, нужно перемешать буквы в ней во всех возможных вариациях и вывести их в списке, и удалить дубликаты, если они есть, например:

```
('a');  ['a']

('ab');  ['ab', 'ba']

('aabb');  ['aabb', 'abab', 'abba', 'baab', 'baba', 'bbaa']
```

я написал такой код, но он работает только при маленькой длине строки, а при большой ответы не совпадают с нужными.

```
import math
import random
def permutations(string):
    lst=[]
    for i in range(0,math.factorial(len(string))):
        lst.append(''.join(random.sample(string,len(string))))
    asm=set()
    for i in lst:
        asm.add(''.join(i))
    return sorted(asm)
```

пожалуйста, объясните решение задачи,
вопрос взял отсюда:
https://www.codewars.com/kata/5254ca2719453dcc0b00027d/train/python

Comment: Я вас расстрою - ваш код и при малой длине строки не работает. Вы берете случайным образом сочетания букв и почему-то думаете, что эти сочетания не будут повторяться. В худшем (хотя и очень-очень маловероятном случае) у вас на выходе будет одна единственная комбинация букв.

Comment: @Эникейщик я думал, что здесь подойдут перестановки: P(n)=n!. Именно поэтому я и беру факториал от длины символов. Каким тогда образом сделать так, чтобы абсолютно все возможные вариации были созданы?

Comment: Перестановки подойдут. Но вы не делаете перестановки. В модуле random есть нужная вам функция, но поскольку задача судя по всему учебная, то лучше вам сделать ее самостоятельно.

Comment: @Эникейщик Вы имеете в виду shuffle?

Comment: В модуле itertools, пардон.

Comment: @Эникейщик спасибо за совет, пойду изучать

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39684371/4928642

Comment: @Qwertiy По вашей ссылке перестановки в лексикографическом порядке. Не то, что требуется в вопросе.

Comment: @MiniMax, это именно то, что требуется. sort(); do {} while (next_permutation());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю два варианта:

**1)** С помощью модуля `itertools`.

```
from itertools import permutations as perm

def permutations(string):
    return list(''.join(tup) for tup in set(perm(string)))
```

**2)** Рекурсивный.

```
def perm(string, accum):
    if len(string) == 0:
        return [accum]  

    res = []
    for i, letter in enumerate(string):
        res += perm(string[:i] + string[i + 1:], accum + letter)

    return res

def permutations(string):
    return list(set(perm(string, '')))
```

**Объяснение**

Имеем набор из трёх букв `abc`.
Начинаем собирать все возможные перестановки:

1. Первой буквой может быть любая из набора, соответственно строка может иметь три разных начала: `a`, `b`, `c`. Выбирая какую-либо букву, мы должны удалить её из набора, так как она уже использована.
2. Вторую букву выбираем из оставшихся в наборе, в данном случае их две. Добавляем её к уже имеющейся строке (аккумулятору) и удаляем её из набора.
3. Третья буква автоматом идёт в аккумулятор, так как последняя в наборе.

```
'a', в наборе остаётся 'bc'.
    'ab' в наборе остаётся 'c'
        'abc', набор пустой
    'ac' в наборе остаётся 'b'
        'acb', набор пустой

'b', в наборе остаётся 'ac'.
    'ba' в наборе остаётся 'c'
        'bac', набор пустой
    'bc' в наборе остаётся 'a'
        'bca', набор пустой     

'c', в наборе остаётся 'ab'.
    'ca' в наборе остаётся 'b'
        'cab', набор пустой
    'cb' в наборе остаётся 'a'
        'cba', набор пустой
```

4. Для удаления дубликатов все полученные перестановки прогоняем через `set()` .